# Nativescipt RadSideDrawer

Tags: angular, nativescript-angular, nativescript-plugin

I have being encountering error when trying to add RADSIDEDRAWER to my Nativescript-Angular-Project since 5 days ago. I have install the plugin as directed in the nativescript doc. Also After Installation i have deleted the (Node_module,Platforms,Hook, Webpack.config.js,package-lock.json folder and run npm install) but still no lock. Please any assistance will be highly appreciated

1. Successfully installed on device with identifier 'BVK6R20525018511'.
   Restarting application on device BVK6R20525018511... Successfully
   synced application org.nativescript.nsngcourse on device
   BVK6R20525018511. System.err: An uncaught Exception occurred on
   "main" thread. System.err: Unable to create application
   com.tns.NativeScriptApplication: com.tns.NativeScriptException:
   Error calling module function  System.err: TypeError: Class extends
   value undefined is not a constructor or null System.err: File:
   (file:
   node_modules\nativescript-ui-sidedrawer\ui-sidedrawer.common.js:27:66)
   System.err:  System.err: StackTrace: System.err:
   ../node_modules/nativescript-ui-sidedrawer/ui-sidedrawer.common.js(file:
   node_modules\nativescript-ui-sidedrawer\ui-sidedrawer.common.js:27:66)
   System.err:     at **webpack_require**(file:
   src\webpack\bootstrap:750:0) System.err:     at fn(file:
   src\webpack\bootstrap:120:0) System.err:     at (file:
   node_modules\nativescript-ui-sidedrawer\ui-sidedrawer.android.js:1:0)
   System.err:     at
   ../node_modules/nativescript-ui-sidedrawer/ui-sidedrawer.js(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.nsngcourse/files/app/vendor.js:155379:30)
   System.err:     at **webpack_require**(file:
   src\webpack\bootstrap:750:0) System.err:     at fn(file:
   src\webpack\bootstrap:120:0) System.err:     at
   ../node_modules/nativescript-ui-sidedrawer/angular/fesm2015/nativescript-ui-sidedrawer-angular.js(file:
   node_modules\nativescript-ui-sidedrawer\angular\fesm2015\nativescript-ui-sidedrawer-angular.js:1:0)
   System.err:     at **webpack_require**(file:
   src\webpack\bootstrap:750:0) System.err:     at fn(file:
   src\webpack\bootstrap:120:0) System.err:     at
   ./app/app.module.ts(file: src\app\app.module.ts:1:0) System.err:
   at **webpack_require**(file: src\webpack\bootstrap:750:0)
   System.err:     at fn(file: src\webpack\bootstrap:120:0) System.err:
   at
   (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.nsngcourse/files/app/bundle.js:783:73)
   System.err:     at
   ./main.ts(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.nsngcourse/files/app/bundle.js:849:30)
   System.err:     at **webpack_require**(file:
   src\webpack\bootstrap:750:0) System.err:     at
   checkDeferredModules(file: src\webpack\bootstrap:43:0) System.err:
   at webpackJsonpCallback(file: src\webpack\bootstrap:30:0)
   System.err:     at
   (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.nsngcourse/files/app/bundle.js:2:57)
   System.err:     at require(:1:266) System.err:  System.err:
   System.err: TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a
   constructor or null System.err: System.err: StackTrace: System.err:
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application
   com.tns.NativeScriptApplication: com.tns.NativeScriptException:
   Error calling module function System.err: TypeError: Class extends
   value undefined is not a constructor or null System.err: File:
   (file:
   node_modules\nativescript-ui-sidedrawer\ui-sidedrawer.common.js:27:66)
   System.err:  System.err: StackTrace: System.err:
   ../node_modules/nativescript-ui-sidedrawer/ui-sidedrawer.common.js(file:
   node_modules\nativescript-ui-sidedrawer\ui-sidedrawer.common.js:27:66)
   System.err:     at **webpack_require**(file:
   src\webpack\bootstrap:750:0) System.err:     at fn(file:
   src\webpack\bootstrap:120:0) System.err:     at (file:
   node_modules\nativescript-ui-sidedrawer\ui-sidedrawer.android.js:1:0)
   System.err:     at
   ../node_modules/nativescript-ui-sidedrawer/ui-sidedrawer.js(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.nsngcourse/files/app/vendor.js:155379:30)
   System.err:     at **webpack_require**(file:
   src\webpack\bootstrap:750:0) System.err:     at fn(file:
   src\webpack\bootstrap:120:0) System.err:     at
   ../node_modules/nativescript-ui-sidedrawer/angular/fesm2015/nativescript-ui-sidedrawer-angular.js(file:
   node_modules\nativescript-ui-sidedrawer\angular\fesm2015\nativescript-ui-sidedrawer-angular.js:1:0)
   System.err:     at **webpack_require**(file:
   src\webpack\bootstrap:750:0) System.err:     at fn(file:
   src\webpack\bootstrap:120:0) System.err:     at
   ./app/app.module.ts(file: src\app\app.module.ts:1:0) System.err:
   at **webpack_require**(file: src\webpack\bootstrap:750:0)
   System.err:     at fn(file: src\webpack\bootstrap:120:0) System.err:
   at
   (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.nsngcourse/files/app/bundle.js:783:73)
   System.err:     at
   ./main.ts(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.nsngcourse/files/app/bundle.js:849:30)
   System.err:     at **webpack_require**(file:
   src\webpack\bootstrap:750:0) System.err:     at
   checkDeferredModules(file: src\webpack\bootstrap:43:0) System.err:
   at webpackJsonpCallback(file: src\webpack\bootstrap:30:0)
   System.err:     at
   (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.nsngcourse/files/app/bundle.js:2:57)
   System.err:     at require(:1:266) System.err: System.err:
   System.err: TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a
   constructor or null System.err:     at
   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6654)
   System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(Unknown
   Source:0) System.err:     at
   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2084)
   System.err:     at
   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:109) System.err:
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166) System.err:     at
   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7555)
   System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   System.err:     at
   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:469)
   System.err:     at
   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:963)
   System.err: Caused by: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Error calling
   module function  System.err: TypeError: Class extends value
   undefined is not a constructor or null System.err: File: (file:
   node_modules\nativescript-ui-sidedrawer\ui-sidedrawer.common.js:27:66)
   System.err:  System.err: StackTrace: System.err:
   ../node_modules/nativescript-ui-sidedrawer/ui-sidedrawer.common.js(file:
   node_modules\nativescript-ui-sidedrawer\ui-sidedrawer.common.js:27:66)
   System.err:     at **webpack_require**(file:
   src\webpack\bootstrap:750:0) System.err:     at fn(file:
   src\webpack\bootstrap:120:0) System.err:     at (file:
   node_modules\nativescript-ui-sidedrawer\ui-sidedrawer.android.js:1:0)
   System.err:     at
   ../node_modules/nativescript-ui-sidedrawer/ui-sidedrawer.js(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.nsngcourse/files/app/vendor.js:155379:30)
   System.err:     at **webpack_require**(file:
   src\webpack\bootstrap:750:0) System.err:     at fn(file:
   src\webpack\bootstrap:120:0) System.err:     at
   ../node_modules/nativescript-ui-sidedrawer/angular/fesm2015/nativescript-ui-sidedrawer-angular.js(file:
   node_modules\nativescript-ui-sidedrawer\angular\fesm2015\nativescript-ui-sidedrawer-angular.js:1:0)
   System.err:     at **webpack_require**(file:
   src\webpack\bootstrap:750:0) System.err:     at fn(file:
   src\webpack\bootstrap:120:0) System.err:     at
   ./app/app.module.ts(file: src\app\app.module.ts:1:0) System.err:
   at **webpack_require**(file: src\webpack\bootstrap:750:0)
   System.err:     at fn(file: src\webpack\bootstrap:120:0) System.err:
   at
   (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.nsngcourse/files/app/bundle.js:783:73)
   System.err:     at
   ./main.ts(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.nsngcourse/files/app/bundle.js:849:30)
   System.err:     at **webpack_require**(file:
   src\webpack\bootstrap:750:0) System.err:     at
   checkDeferredModules(file: src\webpack\bootstrap:43:0) System.err:
   at webpackJsonpCallback(file: src\webpack\bootstrap:30:0)
   System.err:     at
   (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.nsngcourse/files/app/bundle.js:2:57)
   System.err:     at require(:1:266) System.err:  System.err:
   System.err: TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a
   constructor or null System.err:     at
   com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Native Method) System.err:     at
   com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Runtime.java:674) System.err:     at
   com.tns.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:666) System.err:     at
   com.tns.NativeScriptApplication.onCreate(NativeScriptApplication.java:21)
   System.err:     at
   android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
   System.err:     at
   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6636)
   System.err:     ... 8 more

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it work by removing the mode_module,hook,platform,webpack.config.js,package-lock.json folder and editing the dependencies for radsidedrawer from 9.0.3 to 8.0.1 and run npm install